# Pseudocode asking input of 10 numbers for an array, output in reverse order

Tags: arrays, for-loop, pseudocode

I am very stuck on the following question and am in need of some guidance:

"Write pseudocode for a program that allows a user to enter 10 positive numbers and displays them in reverse order of entry. The numbers that the user enters should be stored in an array called `numberList`. You need plan the logic to loop through and display the array in reverse order. Organize your code into declarations, housekeeping, detailLoop, and endOfProgram tasks."

I believe that I would use a for-loop for this problem. I've come up with the following declarations (but these may be wrong, I am brand new at this):

```
    num positiveNum = 0
    num SIZE = 10
    num ARRAY_LIMIT = SIZE - 1
    num numberList[SIZE] = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Note - EDIT: I know that I need to have the loop run 10 times, each time asking for new user input. In python, I would use append to add on new user input values each time, but do not know how append translates into pseudocode. I am unsure if I will be using a for-loops or while- loop or both! The loops will end once elements in the array have reached the ARRAY_LIMIT...

Thanks! Anything would help at this point!

Comment: `reversed_list = number_list[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Put the ten numbers in an array. Then create another array called reverseArray where reverseArray[i]=originalArray[9-i].

reverseArray will be the original input in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop that runs 10 times.

Each time the loop runs, get some input from the user and append it to the end of a list.

Once that's done, you can either iterate through the list in reverse, or use the `reverse()` function to flip the list around, and print each element of it.